# Find time taken by each task while running multiple task in C#

Tags: c#, task

I trying to find out if there is any built in method or property which tells about time taken by each task while executing multiple tasks (say adding tasks in an array or list and executing all of them at the same time and waiting to finish all of them). And in between of this process if one or more task takes a lot more time than expected, I should be able to identify that task and remove that task from the array or list. If there is no in-built method or property then is there any other way to find out this?

Comment: use separate `StopWatch` instances...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to beat a good old `Stopwatch`, from the System.Diagnostics library. Set up a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,StopWatch>`, with the integer representing the managed thread ID of the task (you can also key it to Task objects or the Threads themselves depending on how you're spinning them up, or you can set up a communication token including a "Cancel" method). Each thread or task, when it starts, should create a Stopwatch, add it into the Dictionary, then Start() it, before continuing to do its work. When it's done, it should Stop() its stopwatch and remove it from the Dictionary (you can have it put the resulting Elapsed time into a ConcurrentQueue that you can use in the supervisor thread to log running times; the dictionary is used to track running times of active threads so your supervisor can manage them). Your supervisor thread can then periodically check for tasks taking much longer than average, and when it finds one, it can trip the cancellation token and remove the entry from the Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

It's specifically made for timing the execution of your code accurately.
It sounds like you are running these tasks in parallel probably with the TPL, if that is the case, maybe you can assign a single [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783029(v=vs.110).aspx) to all the Tasks you are creating then use that token to stop all the tasks simultaneously if the StopWatch exceeds the time limit.

Alternatively, assign a StopWatch separately to each of your tasks and have them stop whenever necessary.